# MySQL Join AND SUM on Both Tables

Tags: mysql, sum, left-join

I'm trying to join two tables and sum the results from both tables columns but I can't figure out. I'm doing it in Joomla.

invoices table:

| id | owner | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 300.00 |
| 2 | 123 | 125.00 |
| 3 | 144 | 200.00 |
| 4 | 166 | 155.00 |

expenses table:

| id | owner | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 10.00 |
| 2 | 123 | 50.00 |
| 3 | 144 | 50.00 |

results:

| owner | invoices | expenses |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 425.00 | 60.00 |
| 144 | 200.00 | 50.00 |
| 166 | 155.00 | 0.00 |

Comment: Consider properly normalising your data first - always question yourself if you end up with two tables with identical columns, you should have a single table for transactions and a transaction type column. You then do not need to aggregate nd join each table.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the expect results. I do `LEFT JOIN` for results from both tables.

```
SELECT l.`owner`, invoices, IFNULL(expenses,0) FROM
(
  SELECT 
    `owner`, SUM(amount) AS invoices
  FROM
    invoices
  GROUP BY
    `owner`
) AS l LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT 
    `owner`, SUM(amount) AS expenses 
  FROM
    expenses
  GROUP BY
    `owner`
) AS r ON l.`owner` = r.`owner`
```

Comment: We would only have to adjust the select a bit since the owner field is ambiguous

Comment: @Luis Fernando Prudencio Cruz you are right. It's done.

Comment: This is missing GROUP BY t1.owner I beleive but even then the expenses TOTAL gets multiplied by the t1.owner amount of rows so this still does not work for me.

Comment: @user1680430 answer modified.